# realmファイルにパスワードを設定することはできますか？

Tags: realm

Realm databaseとRealm Strudioを利用しています。
アプリ内のrealmファイルのセキュリティの強化したいと考えており、
Realm Strudioでrealmファイル(default.realm)を開くときに、
パスワード入力などを求めることはできるのでしょうか？

アプリから何らかの方法でrealmファイルにアクセスできる状態になったときに、
第三者にrealmファイルの中身を見られることを避けたいと考えております。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmは暗号化キーによる暗号化をサポートしているので、それが期待する機能になります。

> Realm supports encrypting the database file on disk with AES-256+SHA2 by supplying a 64-byte encryption key when creating a Realm.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#encryption

Realmファイルに暗号化キーを設定した場合、ファイルを読み書きするには必ず暗号化キーが必要になります。

暗号化キーによって暗号化されたRealmファイルは、第三者がファイルにアクセスできる状態であっても暗号化キーを知らなければ内容を読み取ることはできません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
回答内容が期待する機能です。

サンプルコードの[ViewContoller.m](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift/Encryption/ViewController.swift)を参考に作成したのですが、Realm StrudioやRealm Browserで開くことができません。
keychainIdentifierに「1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234」を設定し、
Realm Strudioで開くときは「31323334353637383930313233343536373839303132333435363738393031323334353637383930313233343536373839303132333435363738393031323334」を入力したのですが、 https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbFcO.jpg のようなエラーで開くことができません。

設定方法が誤っているのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こちらの質問でRealmStudioのエラーは解決できました。
ありがとうございました。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69844/realm%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%83%99%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b9%e3%81%ae%e6%9a%97%e5%8f%b7%e5%8c%96%e3%82%92%e6%8c%87%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e5%a0%b4%e5%90%88%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a9%e3%81%a1%e3%82%89%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%88%e3%81%b0%e8%89%af%e3%81%84%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93